# Should email verification be GET or POST?

Tags: rest, http

I'm sending an email address to my server for verification. I'm neither creating a resource nor reading one, so neither POST nor GET seem to fit. What makes sense here?

Comment: Why shouldn't `POST` fit? It clearly is defined as an [all-purpose tool](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) when other operations do not fit. Its semantics are further defined by the implementor of the service. While the majority of people only used it for creating resources it is not limited to it actually

Comment: `POST` is fine in your case. Don't worry about this too much, otherwise you will never finish what you have in plan :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) is not only meant for creating resources. It's kinda a *catch all* method and should fit the needs you described in your question.

From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the
> representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
> own specific semantics.